# Yii2 app alongside CraftCMS utilizing YII2

Tags: yii, yii2

Currently I have an app that is built INSIDE of CraftCMS plugins. I'm extracting these classes out and into an independent Yii2 framework.

How does Yii2 framework know WHEN to receive a request and process it? For example with Craft I am able to POST to `/index.php?action=/ctrl/ctrlname/action&data=somedata` but I'm unsure of how to do this with Yii?

I want to run CraftCMS and a separate Yii2 framework on the same server (for now) so JS will be making `$.ajax()` requests to the backend and I need CraftCMS to pick up certain ones and Yii2 to pick up other ones.

Comment: update your question and add the controller/action that you use for the same action you have in Craft ..

Comment: @scaisEdge the controller/action is just a test action. controller = TestController.php and the action is actionTestSetup(); doesn't do anything special just running a print_r() in the action to see if it ever ges there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to write a custom index.php file that would `require_once $path` where $path was the path to the correct app index.php file for bootstrapping.

This way in my custom index.php it would detect which app I wanted to load (based on a url component in the request) and then bootstrap appropriately.